# use cider debugging inside a deftest

Tags: testing, emacs, clojure, spacemacs, cider

I'd like to debug my test when it is run by CIDER:

```
(let [test-system (atom (new-test-system))]
 (some-setup-code)
 (deftest my-test
   ;uses test-system in here)
```

As you see, my tests are wrapped in a `let`, which gets debugged as normal: I can hit `c` to move through the forms until it gets to the `deftest`, then the debugger quits, and `my-test` is highlighted in red, ready to be debugged when run.

When I run the test with `, t t` it doesn't debug, it passes as normal. I expected it to break and let me debug inside the test.

What am I doing wrong? I'm rather new to CIDER.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar issue.

Even if I instrument a function that is called from within the `deftest` I can't debug it when I execute the test with `, t t` (`cider-test-run-focused-test`).
It seems that this action clears out the instrumentation.

If I run the test manually via `(clojure.test/run-tests)` (switching to the namespace before e.g. via `cider-repl-set-ns`) I can debug both tests and auxiliary functions without problems.

Comment: Note that it should work fine with `cider-test-run...` if the instrumented function is in another namespace.